# User-space приложение для доступа к загружаемому модулю ядра Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, модули

Всем привет! Имеется загружаемый модуль ядра для Linux, одной из задач которого является получение информации о процессах. Возникла необходимость написать user-space приложение, с помощью которого можно было бы использовать функции данного модуля(и передавать в функции модуля параметры), а также получать информацию, которую возвращают функции модуля. Хотелось бы узнать, какие варианты существуют для решения данной задачи. Буду благодарен за любую литературу по данной теме. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Чаще всего модули ядра общаются с внешим миром через интерфейс файловой системы proc. вот например https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-linux_kernel_26/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Возникла необходимость написать user-space приложение, с помощью
>   которого можно было бы использовать функции данного модуля

В таком виде, как сформулировано - невозможно. Разработчик модуля ядра должен предусмотреть (заранее) некий механизм взаимодействия с приложениями. Наиболее часто используемые типы такого взаимодействия:

1. Использование *ioctl()* вызовов. Но это годится только для модулей, создающих устройство в каталоге */dev*;
2. Как уже сказал Mike - через интерфейс псевдофайловой системы */proc*. Любой модуль ядра может создать там свои файлы, писать в них и читать данные из них. Опять-таки, об этом должен позаботиться разработчик модуля.
3. Посылка сигнала процессу пользователя.

Ну больше и не знаю... Если разработчик модуля не предусмотрел ничего из этого, то тогда - никак!